# Program to batch crop photos by certain amount of pixels from each side

Tags: gratis, osx, images, image-processing, image-editing

I realize that Preview can crop a photo by either selecting an area and pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>. However, I need to crop ~100 photos by removing an EXACT amount of pixels from the bottom and right sides. I am thus looking for software that can...

- Crop a specific amount of pixels from specific sides of the photos.
- Preferably, crop multiple photos at once ("batch-crop").

**Does such a program exist for OS X 10.9?**

Answer (score 8):

You can use [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php)

- free
- open source
- cross-platform
- CLI (i.e. can batch process)
- can [crop](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop) pixel-specifically: e.g. `mogrify -crop 40x30+10+10  crop.gif`

Comment: You should probably read http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#mogrify_not

Comment: @SteveBarnes Thanks, providing link + command name is indeed clearer.

Answer (score 1):

[**BatchCrop**](http://batchcrop.com) can do this. Use the "fixed crop" feature with "margin" parameters.

- Process a batch of files at once
- Automatic intelligent cropping
- User parameterized cropping
- [...]
- No installation required
- Available for Mac OS X and Windows
- Unlicensed version has full functionality with limitations related to file count, and occasional reminders.